# Bad Residential Wiring - Dead circuits and circuits go on and off randomly

Tags: wiring, bad-wiring

We moved into a home that is about 30 years old ten years ago.

Our hallway lights are on a a circuit that is usually dead, but occasionally comes on for a few minutes or so, sometimes a few hours.  When I turn the panel off to do work, that sometimes seems to make these lights come on.

We have at least one circuit that is almost always dead.  I have one outlet in our master bedroom that works, but it has 3 black wires that are not hot tied together.  There are three other outlets in the room and I'll add more details about those soon.

The other day, I tried connecting the 3 black wires to the hot wire to see if it out make one or more of our dead circuits alive.  Instead it melted the plastic wing nut.  I smelled the plastic smell in at least one other room that had 3 dead circuits.  So, I am guessing that maybe I need to connect these black wires in a different way.

Can someone please explain how I go about connecting these black wires, maybe one by one?  And, how I test to see that things are safe and working.

I bought a Kaiweets HT112B multimeter because it looked somewhat easier to use and maybe has some neat features that older multimeters don't have.  I also have 3 circuit testers that tell me if the outlet is wired correctly and also shows the voltage.  For our house, it looks like it is usually 118 or 119.  I can add more details to this question as time goes by.

I really appreciate the suggestions so far and I will update this question with more information after I hire the right electrcian(s) to help.  Diagnosing this problem is time consuming and I'm hoping it will make sense to try and repair our wiring rather than opening up the drywall and ripping everything out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120359/discussion-on-question-by-jqueryhtmlcss-bad-residential-wiring-dead-circuits-a).

Answer (score 4):

Your house is a fire hazard.
You need to hire a certified electrician to inspect and correct all defective circuits.
If you fix it yourself, your insurance company will read this and deny you any future compensation anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I will not fix it myself.  For the record, I will hire a certified electrician.  I would like to get information from this community that I can share with the electrician.  I will not hold anyone liable here as if I really have the power to do that anyway.

Comment: The electrician will not need the help of this community. You really do need the help of the electrician.

Comment: Loose connections cause heat and or dropout or worse, fire and toxic PVC smell

Comment: Here is a slow but somewhat certain method of determining the hard connected connections. Intermittent s maybe. | Turn off ALL mains power. CHECK ALL OUTLETS for lack if power.  | Use meter on ohms, long wire and two people. Systemstically test for continuity between each combination of wire ends. End1 - long wire ,- one meter probe - meter ,- other probe ,- End2. You need a book with each end in each room well identified in advance. Call out commands for each change or use walky-talky and record results. | Power on and off changes MAY be due to some outlets being wired to ...

Comment: Switched sides of others. So do above with all outlet switches on (if you have switched outlets). Once above is done turn off all switches if any and repeat. Concentrate on intermittent outlets first. | You could start first test working on the unconnected black wires. | You can make some shortcuts in above as if A connects to B and not C then if E connects to B it should not connect to C either. | IF intermittents are true intermittents they are more liable to be open circuit at low voltage.

Comment: One electrician did notice 70 volts when testing an outlet.  I forgot about that.    So, this is very helpful information that I can pass on to another electrician that might not think of this at first.  I think it could save a lot of time but starting with your idea.

Comment: Say we have 45 outlets, how much time would you estimate it would take to run a test like this if I have two electricians?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS the amount of time it takes will depend on what and how many problems are present and how intuitively the house is wired.  If you want to decrease the labor cost a bit, make a neat diagram of the house including all electrical outlets and switches.  Make sure it is large enough to be easy to work with.  Use multiple sheets or larger paper as necessary and make it available to the electricians so they can go straight to locating circuits and determining the wiring pattern. Also make sure ahead of time to have at least one working bulb in every light fixture.

Comment: As for any circuits that don't come on during testing, typically these can still be traced back to somewhere with the use of a toner.